# Firefox 4 Windows only "bug" with :after/:before CSS selectors?

Tags: windows, firefox, css

I think this is a bug, and if so im going to report it, but even if it is a bug i need a way to fix this. I'd really like to not have to use an image but here's the problem:

**JSBin Example:** http://jsbin.com/alame5

**Chrome 3 on Mac** (and Windows) 
[image]

**Firefox 4 on Mac**
[image]

Works the same on IE8 and IE9 as above

Now, **Firefox 4 on Windows 7**
[image]

Comment: That's Firefox **4**.  It works on my Win7 FF4.

Comment: I think that is Firefox 4, not 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the same affect can be made with one **p:before**:

```
.twitterfeed p:before {
  content:"\00a0";
  display:block; /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-20px; /* value = - border-top-width - border-bottom-width */
  right:25px; /* controls horizontal position */
  width:0;
  height:0;
  border-width:0 0 20px 20px; /* vary these values to change the angle of the vertex */
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:transparent transparent transparent #fff;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

I only changed the border-width, according to [this](http://mrcoles.com/blog/callout-box-css-border-triangles-cross-browser/) page.

But still, i'm pretty sure its a FF4 bug..

Comment: what about the code above? i believe it does the same triangle - with only the right side (top right to bottom left) has the gray weird border

Comment: Dude, you rock. I was thinking that you were just showing a shortcut, i didnt realize it looks 100x better. Thanks man!